# Incorrect arrow function minification inside function argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, minify, reactjs.net

**TL;DR**

An arrow function `(x, y) => { x[y.k] = y.v; return x; }` is minified to `(x, y) => x[y.k] = y.v, x` inside a function call, so the use of the comma `,` without the curl braces `{ }` messes up the function arguments.

Is this my mistake, or an erroneous over-enthusiastic minifier?

I am using [ReactJS.NET's `BabelBundle` in MVC](https://reactjs.net/bundling/weboptimizer.html).

**More in-depth investigation and resolution**

In a small React component, which is bundled with a `BabelBundle` in [ReactJS.NET](https://reactjs.net/), the following code was causing me errors:

```
const fields = this.props.children.reduce((obj, field) => {
    obj[field.props.field_key] = field.props.field_value;
    return obj;
}, {});
const fieldsString = JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2);
```

The idea is that given an array of key-value pairs `[ { field_key: 'x', field_value: 'y' }, ... ]`, it should create a flat object from those pairs: `{ x: y, ... }`.

When minified, the following code was generated:

```
const n = this.props.children.reduce(
    (n, t) => n[t.props.field_key] = t.props.field_value,
    n,
    {}),
t = JSON.stringify(n, null, 2);
```

Which gave me the following error: `` ReferenceError: "can't access lexical declaration `n' before initialization" ``.

Notice how this arrow function:

```
(obj, field) => {
    obj[field.props.field_key] = field.props.field_value;
    return obj;
}
```

was minified to, using the comma operator `,` to get rid of the `return` keyword:

```
(obj, field) => obj[field.props.field_key] = obj.props.field_value, obj
```

But it did this within a (`reduce`) function call, where the comma `,` has its own meaning (to separate function arguments). That made the call, which should have been `reduce(lambda, initialValue)`, become `reduce(lambda, uninitialisedVariable, initialValue)`.

The uninitialised variable ended up with the variable name `n`, which is the same as the one to which the result of the `reduce` is assigned. This caused the lexical error (otherwise with `var` it becomes an `undefined` error) when it was used as the initial value to the `reduce` function.

The fix for my code was simple: to replace the arrow function with an old-style function:

```
const fields = this.props.children.reduce(function (obj, field) {
    obj[field.props.field_key] = field.props.field_value;
    return obj;
}, {});
const fieldsString = JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2);
```

Because the old-style function cannot have its curly braces `{ ... }` removed, then it is minified without clobbering the function call:

```
const n = this.props.children.reduce(
    function (n, t) {
        return n[t.props.field_key] = t.props.field_value, n
    },
    {}),
t = JSON.stringify(n, null, 2);
```

**Now, the point of my question is this:** is the minifier's behaviour caused by a mistake of my own, or is it an error in the minifier itself?

And if it is in fact an error in the minifier, where can I report it? I was not exactly sure which version of which tool my bundle is being minified with.

Comment: why not try with `(x, y) => (x[y.k] = y.v, x)`?

Comment: That would probably also work, but fixing my original code isn't the issue here. It's about whether the minifier is performing an incorrect rewrite on valid code, or whether I made a mistake that is causing it to do so in turn.

Comment: of course, this is a minifier bug. It should translate all valid javascript correctly.